# Standard persistent disk data loss

Tags: google-compute-engine

I moved a bunch of files to a disk that I attached to a Google VM instance. All the files got transferred fine under their respective folder, but now (after few days of the transfer) I can't seem to find the folders that I created nor the files.

What could be the cause and more importantly, are the files recoverable? The original instance never got deleted, and I made sure to check the option to keep the disk after VM removal just in case.

It's really odd that all folders and files were removed. Type ls in the disk main folder results in no information, whereas before it gave the name of all folders that I created.

Comment: You can refer to this thread where similar question was answered (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/1WD8i881M3I)

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause of this issue is if you reboot the instance and disk auto mount is not set on the VM. You can set the instance to auto-mount disks at startup by editing [/etc/fstab](https://wiki.debian.org/fstab).